# Jboss errors while starting

Tags: jboss7.x

I am working on Spring mvc app using Jboss 7.1.1. When I start my server, following error appears:

```
13:23:34,569 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 8667ms - Started 377 of 456 s
ervices (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Following is the complete console while starting jboss:

```
Calling "F:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: F:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dg
c.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.d
efault.config=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

13:23:26,259 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:23:26,550 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:23:26,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
13:23:28,015 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:23:28,032 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:23:28,048 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
13:23:28,069 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:23:28,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:23:28,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:23:28,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:23:28,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
13:23:28,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:23:28,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
13:23:28,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:23:28,242 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:23:28,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
13:23:28,523 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
13:23:28,619 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-9090
13:23:28,712 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:23:28,756 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:23:29,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
13:23:29,520 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory F:\jboss-
as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:23:29,656 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
13:23:30,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS]

13:23:30,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "scm.war"
13:23:32,462 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.St
andardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default construc
tor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final
]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

13:23:32,486 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHtt
pAsyncRequestControl due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for
class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final
]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

13:23:32,754 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/scm]] (MSC service thread 1-5) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer t
ypes detected on classpath
13:23:33,054 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,870 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback
.groovy]
13:23:33,061 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,870 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback
-test.xml]
13:23:33,063 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,871 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at
[vfs:/F:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/scm.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
13:23:33,067 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,889 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7c5261f0 - URL [vfs:/F:/jbo
ss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/scm.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] is not of type file
13:23:33,070 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,933 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not se
t
13:23:33,074 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,935 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender
of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
13:23:33,078 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:32,947 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
13:23:33,086 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,016 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - This appender no longer
admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
13:23:33,090 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,016 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - To ensure compatibility,
 wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
13:23:33,096 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,016 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - See also http://logback.
qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
13:23:33,100 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,035 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@49c1354 - Will use zip comp
ression
13:23:33,106 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: d:
/scmlogs.log
13:23:33,112 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,045 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to
[d:/scmlogs.log]
13:23:33,115 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.
bizmerlin] to ALL
13:23:33,118 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,048 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT log
ger to INFO
13:23:33,121 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,049 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [F
ILE] to Logger[ROOT]
13:23:33,123 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,049 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
13:23:33,127 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5) 13:23:33,051 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@22b8f229 - Registering current co
nfiguration as safe fallback point
13:23:33,131 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-5)
13:23:33,220 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/scm]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet
'route'
13:23:33,971 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
13:23:34,557 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /scm
13:23:34,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:23:34,569 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 8667ms - Started 377 of 456 s
ervices (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
13:23:34,851 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "scm.war"
```

Following is my standalone.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/dbname</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>xxxxxx</user-name>
                        <password>xxxxxxx</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
            <show-model value="true"/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
            <properties>
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                    1
                </property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="9090"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the two warnings (WARN) - standard output on this version of jboss

Try changing jndi name to look like this and make sure you have MySQL driver under jboss module directory
jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS"

try this url
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html

Comment: This link https://developer.jboss.org/thread/231638 explains why the warnings can be ignored.